# Capistrano 3 can't access rbenv ruby on remote server or shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv, capistrano3

Can't get capistrano 3 to make use or remote server rbenv ruby: 
`Capistrano Version: 3.6.1 (Rake Version: 11.3.0)`

```
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: which ruby exit status: 1
which ruby stdout: which: no ruby in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin)
which ruby stderr: Nothing written
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/command.rb:100:in `exit_status='
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `execute_command'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:60:in `capture'
config/deploy.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `within'
config/deploy.rb:82:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/Users/victorstan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
```

My setup:

`deploy.rb`

```
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '1.9.3-p551' # same as in .ruby-version file
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash -l'
set :pty, true

within release_path do
    ruby_v = capture("which ruby")
    puts "Ruby version: #{ruby_v}"
end
```

`Capfile`

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Extra rails commands
require "capistrano/rails/collection"

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

`config / deploy / staging.rb`

```
set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w(password),
    password: 'xxx',
    user: 'xxx',
}
```

Comment: I wonder if that may be because you have `ssh_options`, check capistrano-rbenv source -> https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake

Comment: btw which gem versions are you using?

Comment: @faron in that case the only thing that changes is that I am asked to login and I see an additional message besides the problems listed above: `Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.`

Comment: Capistrano Version: 3.6.1 (Rake Version: 11.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with capistrano and non-interactive shells, rbenv configurations have to be put in `.bashrc` instead of other bash profile files.

In my case I moved

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

to `.bashrc` and that solved my problem.